# Web database implementation

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, datagrid, mean-stack

I would like to start a web project and need some direction where to look. I am now using Excel for sales forecasting (and analyzing purchase/sales/inventory), however the amount of data is starting to exceed Excel design tolerances.
Here is a very much simplified screenshot from Excel of what I am talking about:
[Sample table/grid. Purchase/Sales fields are actual input from the user, Inventory and Inv wks are calculated. (also all fields in Aug column are calculated, they are just totals, no user input)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgSeW.png)

So my idea is to store the data in a db (I have some experience with sqlite, plus I've layed around with mongodb) and a web interface to retrieve this data from DB, display it to the user, allow user to make changes to it via the web interface and save the data back to the db. It is important that the web interface is dynamic, so that all totals/subtotals/other calculated fields are updated instantly once user update some figures in Purchase/Sales fileds. Export to/import from Excel would be nice as well.
I tried researching the subject, but the variety of tools is overwhelming on one hand; on the other I can't seem to find the ones that do exactly what I need. (I've mostly checked into Mongo-Express-Angular-Node, ag-grid).
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's a broad question, but in your situation I'd use sqllite just because is lighter. In both mongodb and sqllite you could import .csv and perform updates, inserts etc.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I export db in JSON, use ag-grid for user to handle this data, then save/export it from ag-grid to CSV and import this CSV back into sqlite? I was wondering if there was a more straightforward interaction between a db and grid-like JS frontend.